# Covert date format from 2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z to Wed Nov 13 18:06:37 +0000 2013

Tags: php, date

How do I convert the date format  from `2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z` to `Wed Nov 13 18:06:37 +0000 2013` without using string functions like substr. This date format is being used by Gnip. Not sure what format it is.

I tried using the date function

```
$postedTime = "2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z";
date($postedTime,"D M d H:i:s O Y");
```

But I get an error since `$postedTime` is a string and not long variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use substr() when you can use functions designed specifically for working with dates?

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z');
echo $date->format('r Y');
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.org/mOsep4JB)

Comment: Thank you that worked. Although i changed the format 
    $date = new DateTime('2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z');
    echo $date->format("D M d H:i:s O Y");

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the order in your date function

```
date('format string', $time)
```

So you want:

```
date("D M d H:i:s O Y", strtotime($postedTime));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the string in a `DateTime` object with

```
$date = new DateTime($postedTime);
```

Then you may need to change the time zone (since your `postedTime` is timezone Z for Zulu)

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
```

and maybe also add or subtract a suitable offset `DateInterval`.

Finally, if you need a timestamp for use in `date`, you do so with `[getTimeStamp][1]`.

```
$ts  = $date->getTimeStamp();
```

If you have all datetimes in Zulu, just use

```
$date = new DateTime($postedTime);
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date->getTimeStamp());
```

or if you do not need the timestamp,

```
$date = new DateTime($postedTime);
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You should get the same date you entered. If it is offset one or more hours plus or minus, you have [a time zone problem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).